# firebase PushID loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to loop over the database and return all the events from "eventList" that match the current userID.  My issue here is that I'm having trouble simply returning a list of the postID's.  I'm either getting "eventList" or "undefined" as a result.  How can I loop over the database and return the postID's under "eventList"?

I have the following database structure:

```
{
  "eventList" : {
    "-LQ68rGmj_OYShda3tV9" : {
      "name" : "Christmas",
      "user" : "8eZcncLHPCWtuuhw90HRr79f0VO2"
    },
      "-L23Tr87ejdjh9osnG" : {
      "name" : "easter",
      "user" : "7gjsuhv84mvkkslv0jlssvghdasd"
    }

  },
  "userProfile" : {
    "8eZcncLHPCWtuuhw90HRr79f0VO2" : {
      "firstName" : "M"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code I've been working with:

```
this.postRef = firebase.database().ref('/eventList');
this.postRef.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key; // null


  });
  console.log(this.postRef.key);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Aren't you supposed to `console.log` inside the `.then(function(){...})`? And wouldn't `this.postRef.key` **not** point to the snapshot's key?

Comment: Yeah, one of my mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looping inside the node and getting each value, also print the data inside your promise, since `.once` handles asynchronous work and if you try to get your key outside `.then` it will be null, also handle a catch error if the promise fails.

```
 this.postRef = firebase.database().ref('/eventList');
    this.postRef.once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {

     const eventData = snapshot.forEach(data => {
     var key = data.key; 
     console.log(this.postRef.key);
      });

     return eventData;

 }).catch(error => {
         console.log('Error trying to fetch the data.');
        });
```